# Firebase Firestore "Could not build module 'nanopb'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to try out the new firebase firestore database. My pod file has these two dependencies. My project will build if I don't include firestore.

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

Im getting the errors "Could not build module 'nanopb'" and "Unknown type name 'FOUNDATION_EXPORT'" in several places. I was wondering if this is a known issue with Firestore. I figured I could lower the version on Firestore but I'm unsure what to go to.
[image]

My pod versions are:
Firebase 4.5.0
FirebaseFirestore (0.9.1)

UPDATE: I built a new project and ran into the same error. At this point I can only imagine this version of firestore has errors or I'm not including something I need to. Is there a recommended version to use for now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you're on a version of CocoaPods greater than 1.2.1. I was trying this in a Firebase code lab and got the same result as you until I updated to match [the displayed CocoaPods requirement](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-ios/index.html).

I'd thought I had a newer version of CP installed but when I ran `pod --version` it turned out I was running 1.1.1. Oops!

Comment: Firestore's gRPC dependency depends on the CocoaPods fix for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6024 that was deployed in CocoaPods 1.2.0.

Comment: This was right! I got the same answer on from the firebase team on GitHub. Thanks for your help.